# ActionBarSherlock Search widget returns to FirstActivity from SecondActivity

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-annotations

Am using AndroidAnnotations with SherlockActionBar and am trying to implement a search from the MainActivity to a SecondActivity. In the SecondActivity I want to be able to search again. However, if I click on the search widget in the SecondActivity it returns to the first activity. It works fine without the search widget in the SecondActivity.

Thank you in advance!

**MainActivity:**

```
@EActivity
@OptionsMenu(R.menu.main)
public class MainActivity extends TabSwipeActivity {
    SearchView sv;

    @SystemService
    SearchManager searchManager;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
        sv = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search_shows).getActionView();
        sv.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        return true;
    }
}
```

**SearchShowsActivity:**

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_search_shows)
@OptionsMenu(R.menu.search_menu)
public class SearchShowsActivity extends SherlockActivity {

    SearchView sv;

    @SystemService
    SearchManager searchManager;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
        sv = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search_shows).getActionView();
        sv.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));


        return true;
    }
}

    @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);

            // perform search
    }
}
```

**main.xml (menu)**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/search_shows"
      android:title="@string/search_label"
      android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
      android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
      android:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView" />
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<meta-data
        android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
        android:value=".activities.SearchShowsActivity_" />
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity_">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:name=".activities.SearchShowsActivity_">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>
```

Comment: May I ask why are you using so many activities?

Comment: Why not? How is two many? I have more activities besides these two.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of using two Activities with a common search. Have you thought using Fragments? Maybe, I'm just speculating. But, try posting more code to make a better judgement.

Comment: The first activity contains 3 tabbed fragments and the search points to the second activity. Would it be possible with a search fragment instead? This is all the code concerning the search.

Comment: What if you use a Dialog for the Search? And you just keep one activity? If you keep it simple, maybe it would be easier.

Comment: Did not get to fix this. Now I have a search icon starting the second activity in the first activity and have the search widget in the second activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by starting the SearchShowsActivity_ when clicking on the search icon in the MainActivity_:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int itemId = item.getItemId();

    if (itemId == R.id.add_show) {
        SearchShowsActivity_.intent(this).flags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP).start();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In my SearchShowsActivity_ I start the SearchView:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        sv = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search_shows).getActionView();
        sv.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    }

    sv.setFocusable(true);
    sv.setIconified(false);
    sv.requestFocusFromTouch();

    return true;
}
```